# Assign different roles to the same user on different databases on the same server

Tags: postgresql

I've setup our postgresql server with two databases: one production and one training. I would like users to be limited to their true roles in the production database, but be given free reign in the training database.

ie.
Assign one set of roles to a user on one database, and another set of roles to the same user in a different database on the same server.

I figure one way around this would be to create a new "training" role with full access, and then limit this role to just the training database using pg_hba.conf. It's not what I'm hoping for, but is this the only option?

Comment: What are you hoping for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GRANT` different privileges to different `ROLES` in different databases, but `ROLES` are global to the entire server. You might consider using `GROUPS` (prod_dba group vs dev_dba group) and then assign users to the different groups.

Comment: There is [no difference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creategroup.html) between GROUPS and ROLES in Postgres. So the OP needs roles with different privileges for the different databases.

Comment: aye. I still draw a distinction conceptually because I like distinct separation with regards to privs. My bias is to maintain individuals and a collection of individuals/processes vs a catchall that is a union of all capabilities. Because it's in the SQL standard doesn't mean it's a good thing. But, it is nice to add a group to a group now.

Comment: Thanks, that got me going with something similar. I created the role "Training" and then ran:
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "Training";
GRANT INSERT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "Training";
GRANT UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "Training";
GRANT DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "Training";
GRANT REFERENCES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "Training";
GRANT TRIGGER ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "Training";
in the training database.
I then added an existing role, to which all users are assigned, to the role "Training".

Comment: Of course I'll need to run the GRANTs everytime I replace the training database, but at least it allows users to keep their logins and make use of features which rely on unique logins.

Comment: Yup, but it's not that hard to script: `psql -1f sql/perms.sql`.  Something like: https://github.com/sean-/flask-skeleton/blob/c56938143738a98cc299f4474422937ffe2588b2/sql/perms.sql